# Indexing 5 columns

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE active = 1 
  AND deleted = 0 
  AND blocked = 0 
  AND created_at <= NOW() 
  AND last_action_at <= NOW() 
LIMIT 5000;
```

I have an index set on `(deleted, active)`, so it reduces me some rows, but out of 2,5mln records it still traverses 1,5mln.

I also tried adding the following indexes:

```
(created_at, last_action_at)
(active,deleted,blocked,created_at,last_action_at)
```

But the query doesn't use them, and uses the first one I mentioned instead. I also tried changing range conditions to the first position in WHERE clause, but it also didn't change anything.

What's wrong?

Comment: Show us your query plan. Also read http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql. Columns involving `NOW()` will use a scan, not an index. You might be better off with an index on your three constant columns (`active`, `deleted`, `blocked`) in a self join to limit to rows matching them, and only doing a where on `created_at` and `last_action_at`.

Comment: @bishop just to be clear, the `NOW()` do a scan is because almost everything is before `now` so a is almost a scan anyway. Not because is a function?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza The former. `NOW` returns a [constant expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) so it is a candidate for index selection in a theoretical sense, but because it's a `<=` check that's automatically a [range scan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/range-optimization.html) and based on the data it's probably just faster to do a [sequential read](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/how-to-avoid-table-scan.html). What happens depends on the data, though.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong, it's just more efficient to use one index over another. In this case I would bet the index used is the clustered one.

Unless you are selecting a really tiny proportion of rows, no index will help unless it's the clustered one in which case it's really only used because it is actually the data, i.e. it's a slightly more efficiently bounded table scan.

You might also find that an index on a column that allows nulls can be excluded from a search if null is not excluded.

What's your expected final row count and your query plan?

Comment: Well, I now can see that MySQL can't use indexes on datetime columns, I don't know why, but leaving only those two columns and indexing still makes the optimizer using primary key.

Comment: @testtest MySQL *can* index `DATETIME`, but almost always they're evenly distributed with little duplicates, so an index doesn't buy you much. If you rewrite your query into some form of subquery on just the constant columns you *might* get better performance. It all depends on your data.